# How to implement Back button functionality

Tags: android

I have 3 different activity namely, category,sub_category and list of items. In sub_category i created back button using intent Activity. Back button in list_of items should be focus to sub_category. i dont know how to do this.. pls guide me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from category activity
call

```
Intent it=new Intent(category.this,sub_category.class)
startActivityForResult(it);
```

similarly

```
Intent it=new Intent(sub_category.this,list_item.class)
startActivityForResult(it);
```

and in onClickListener of back button simply finish your activity like

```
list_item.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

for going back to previous screen u can call finish() in your current activity. It will remove the current activity from activity Stack and take you to the previous one.