# Exit Android application on back button

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-navigation

I have ImageButton with back arrow in header of my application. When user presses it, I call finish() on current Activity. I also have option for user to go home, but I want to somehow clear Activity history, so when user presses back button on home activity, application closes.

I can also put a parameter to the intent, when calling home activity, but what do I call for application to close?

Comment: that's usually considered a bad practice on android.

Comment: you are implementing a very non-android aplication. you should more follow android guidelines.

Comment: You can call finish() in onBackPressed() method of your first activity

Comment: if we call finish() function  it will show previous activity page if in your application home page contain sthis fuction then it will exit the app

Comment: why is unusual for android? when I click back, finish() is called: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308260/how-to-implement-back-button-functionality . If I call home activity with Intent and click back on the home activity, I expect from application to exit, not to go back on the last activity I was on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to an activity, save that activityContext some where(say in some array of Contexts).

When you press the exit button, you can just loop the array and say `activity.finish()`

So all the activities in the stack are now finished and the user is out of app.

Code may be like this:

```
public class ActivityStack {

    public ArrayList<Context> contextArray=new ArrayList<>(); 

    public void setContext(int i,Context context) {
          contextArray.add(context);
    }

    public void quitApp() {
           for(context:ContextArray) {
              context.finish();  

            }
    }

}
```

**Edit**:
From API 16, `finishAffinity()` method can be used to finish all activities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call an activity with startIntentForResult().
Then in the second activity, you will do something like this :

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

And in the first activity, get this code and close that activity as well :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  if (getParent() == null) {
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
  }
  else {
   getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
  }
  finish();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Intent flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) will suit your purpose.

Example for starting your Activities without a history:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExampleActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
//to remove application from task manager
public void onQuitPressed() {

    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but all activities remain on the stack when I call this. I simply lose all data for my application, but the activities remain.

Answer (score 0):

When you close your last activity consider the app as closed. The lifecycle of the app is beyond your responsibilities as a developer and is handled by the framework. 
When all your activities are finished, the Activity stack (history) is empty, so the next app launch will start your first activity invoking onCreate first.

The singletons and other static fields will be kept however, but Android will clear them as it will need more memory, so that's not a problem.

I'd also suggest you to refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this..

close your services Manually

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewFox_Project.this,RadioService.class);
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    stopService(intent);


    Intent radioTimes = new Intent(NewFox_Project.this,RadioTimeService.class);
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    stopService(radioTimes);

    Intent radioPlyerService = new Intent(NewFox_Project.this,RadioPlayerService.class);
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    stopService(radioPlyerService);

    NewFox_Project.this.finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NewFox_Project.this,RadioService.class);
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        stopService(intent);


        Intent radioTimes = new Intent(NewFox_Project.this,RadioTimeService.class);
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        stopService(radioTimes);

        Intent radioPlyerService = new Intent(NewFox_Project.this,RadioPlayerService.class);
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        stopService(radioPlyerService);

        NewFox_Project.this.finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```